# Can't do Firebase Deploy from SSH with AUTH2

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

After an ssh connection to the firebase/GCP server
I'm trying to deploy:

```
 sudo firebase deploy --only hosting
```

But im getting:

> Failed to get Firebase project progectname. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.

Things I have tried:
1.

```
firebase login
```

Result: send me to OATH2 login address which i paste on the browser, but when i choose the google account and press allow i get:

> This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.

2. 

```
firebase login --no-localhost
```

result:
send me to OATH2 login address which i paste on the browser and gets:

> Authorization Error
> Error 400: invalid_request

3. 

```
firebase login --reauth
```

result:

> same as 1

4. 

firebase login --reauth --no-localhost
result:
same as 2

Please advise.

Comment: firebase login --no-localhost must be asking you to confirm if that's you who ran the command or no? Did you copy the URL from VM console and open in your local browser? That seems to be working for me. Also, what if your `firebase-tools` version ?

Comment: as dharmaraj mentioned what is firebase-tools version?